# OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available

Tags: android, listview, out-of-memory

I am having this error while scrolling list view with items.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available
```

Can anyone help please?

**EDIT**

```
public class ItemsListAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {


    private final float NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_GRID = 2;
    private final int AD_POSITION = 4;

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<ItemResponse>> allData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ItemResponse>>();

    public class ViewHolder {

        // for Item1
        LinearLayout itemLayout1;
        ImageView itemImage1;
        TextView itemDate1;
        ImageView itemTagImage1;
        TextView normalItemPrice1;
        TextView pinnedItemPrice1;
        TextView itemTitle1;
        TextView itemDescription1;

        // for Item2
        LinearLayout itemLayout2;
        ImageView itemImage2;
        TextView itemDate2;
        ImageView itemTagImage2;
        TextView normalItemPrice2;
        TextView pinnedItemPrice2;
        TextView itemTitle2;
        TextView itemDescription2;

        RelativeLayout adLayout;
        ImageView adUnit;
    }

    public ItemsListAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<ItemResponse> data) {

        this.context = context;
        setData(data);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listings2, null);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.itemLayout1      = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1_layout);
        holder.itemImage1       = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image1);   
        holder.itemDate1        = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_date1);
        holder.itemTagImage1    = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tag_image1);
        holder.normalItemPrice1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.normal_item_price1);
        holder.pinnedItemPrice1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pinned_item_price1);
        holder.itemTitle1       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title1);
        holder.itemDescription1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description1);

        holder.itemLayout2      = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2_layout);
        holder.itemImage2       = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image2);   
        holder.itemDate2        = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_date2);
        holder.itemTagImage2    = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tag_image2);
        holder.normalItemPrice2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.normal_item_price2);
        holder.pinnedItemPrice2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pinned_item_price2);
        holder.itemTitle2       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title2);
        holder.itemDescription2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description2);

        holder.adLayout         = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.banner_ad);
        holder.adUnit           = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ad_view_image);

        if (allData.get(position) != null && allData.get(position).size() > 0) {

            setItem1Data(holder, position);
            setItem2Data(holder, position);
        }

        if ((position + 1) % AD_POSITION == 0) {

            // show ad
            holder.adLayout .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //initializeBannerAd(convertView, holder.adUnit);
        } else {
            holder.adLayout .setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        try {
            return allData.get(position);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        try {
            return allData.indexOf(getItem(position));
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return 2;
    }

    private void initData (ArrayList<ItemResponse> data) {

        int numberOfItems = (int) Math.ceil(data.size() / NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_GRID);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<ItemResponse>> tempData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ItemResponse>>(numberOfItems);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {

            ArrayList<ItemResponse> items = new ArrayList<ItemResponse>();
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_GRID; j++) {

                try {
                    items.add(data.get(j));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            tempData.add(i, items);
            // clear 
            data.removeAll(items);
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < tempData.size(); n++) {

            allData.add(tempData.get(n));
        }
    }

    public void setData (ArrayList<ItemResponse> data) {

        allData.clear();
        ArrayList<ItemResponse> mData = new ArrayList<ItemResponse>();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

            mData.add(data.get(i));
        }

        initData(mData);
    }

    public void setItem1Data (ViewHolder holder , int position) {

        try {

            holder.itemLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final ItemResponse current = allData.get(position).get(0);

            if (current != null) {
                if (current.getId() == ForSaleConstants.POST_AD_LISTING_ID) {

                    String postAdPlaceholder = "";
                    ForSaleApplication app = (ForSaleApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
                    if (app.getDefaultLocale().toLowerCase().startsWith(ForSaleConstants.ARABIC_LANGUAGE)) {

                        postAdPlaceholder = PhoneUtils.getStringFromSharedPreference(context, ForSaleConstants.PINNING_IMAGE_AR_URL_KEY);
                    } else {
                        postAdPlaceholder = PhoneUtils.getStringFromSharedPreference(context, ForSaleConstants.PINNING_IMAGE_EN_URL_KEY);
                    }

                    if (PhoneUtils.isEmpty(postAdPlaceholder) == false) {
                        PhoneUtils.setImage(context, holder.itemImage1, postAdPlaceholder);
                    }

                    holder.itemDate1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.itemTagImage1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.normalItemPrice1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.pinnedItemPrice1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.itemTitle1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.itemDescription1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // TODO handle on click listener for placeholder.

                } else {


                    holder.itemDate1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.itemTagImage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.itemTitle1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.itemDescription1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if (current.getImages() != null && current.getImages().size() > 0) {
                        PhoneUtils.setImage(context, holder.itemImage1, current.getImages().get(0));
                    }

                    holder.itemDate1.setText(current.getDatePublished());

                    if (current.isPinned() == true) {
                        holder.itemTagImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.tag_pinned);
                    }

                    if (current.isPinned() == true) {

                        if (ForSaleDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentRegion() != null)
                            holder.pinnedItemPrice1.setText(current.getAskingPrice() + " " + ForSaleDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentRegion().getRegionCode());
                        else
                            holder.pinnedItemPrice1.setText("" + current.getAskingPrice());

                        holder.normalItemPrice1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.pinnedItemPrice1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.itemTagImage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {

                        if (ForSaleDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentRegion() != null)
                            holder.normalItemPrice1.setText(current.getAskingPrice() + " " + ForSaleDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentRegion().getRegionCode());
                        else
                            holder.normalItemPrice1.setText("" + current.getAskingPrice());

                        holder.normalItemPrice1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.pinnedItemPrice1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.itemTagImage1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }



                    holder.itemTitle1.setText(current.getTitle());
                    holder.itemDescription1.setText(current.getDescription());


                    OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(ForSaleConstants.ACTIVITY_ITEM_OBJECT, current);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    };

                    holder.itemImage1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                    holder.itemTitle1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                    holder.itemDescription1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            holder.itemLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void setItem2Data (ViewHolder holder , int position) {

        try {

            holder.itemLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final ItemResponse current = allData.get(position).get(1);

            if (current != null) {
                if (current.getId() == ForSaleConstants.POST_AD_LISTING_ID) {

                    String postAdPlaceholder = "";
                    ForSaleApplication app = (ForSaleApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
                    if (app.getDefaultLocale().toLowerCase().startsWith(ForSaleConstants.ARABIC_LANGUAGE)) {

                        postAdPlaceholder = PhoneUtils.getStringFromSharedPreference(context, ForSaleConstants.PINNING_IMAGE_AR_URL_KEY);
                    } else {
                        postAdPlaceholder = PhoneUtils.getStringFromSharedPreference(context, ForSaleConstants.PINNING_IMAGE_EN_URL_KEY);
                    }

                    if (PhoneUtils.isEmpty(postAdPlaceholder) == false) {
                        PhoneUtils.setImage(context, holder.itemImage2, postAdPlaceholder);
                    } else {
                        PhoneUtils.setImage(context, holder.itemImage2, null, R.drawable.placeholder_squre);
                    }

                    holder.itemDate2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.itemTagImage2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.normalItemPrice2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.pinnedItemPrice2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.itemTitle2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.itemDescription2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // TODO handle on click listener for placeholder.

                } else {


                    holder.itemDate2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.itemTagImage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.itemTitle2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.itemDescription2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    if (current.getImages() != null && current.getImages().size() > 0) {
                        PhoneUtils.setImage(context, holder.itemImage2, current.getImages().get(0));
                    }

                    holder.itemDate2.setText(current.getDatePublished());

                    if (current.isPinned() == true) {
                        holder.itemTagImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tag_pinned);
                    } else {
                        holder.itemTagImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tag);
                    }

                    if (current.isPinned() == true) {

                        if (ForSaleDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentRegion() != null)
                            holder.pinnedItemPrice2.setText(current.getAskingPrice() + " " + ForSaleDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentRegion().getRegionCode());
                        else
                            holder.pinnedItemPrice2.setText("" + current.getAskingPrice());

                        holder.normalItemPrice2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.pinnedItemPrice2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.itemTagImage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {

                        if (ForSaleDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentRegion() != null)
                            holder.normalItemPrice2.setText(current.getAskingPrice() + " " + ForSaleDataManager.getInstance().getCurrentRegion().getRegionCode());
                        else
                            holder.normalItemPrice2.setText("" + current.getAskingPrice());

                        holder.normalItemPrice2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.pinnedItemPrice2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.itemTagImage2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }



                    holder.itemTitle2.setText(current.getTitle());
                    holder.itemDescription2.setText(current.getDescription());


                    OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra(ForSaleConstants.ACTIVITY_ITEM_OBJECT, current);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    };

                    holder.itemImage2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                    holder.itemTitle2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
                    holder.itemDescription2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            holder.itemLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

and also find the loading method, I am implementing on scroll load more items

```
private void loadData (boolean inBackground) {


            int categoryId = -1;

            if (mParentCategory != null) 
                categoryId = mParentCategory.getId();


            mIsInBackground = inBackground;
            if (mIsInBackground == false)
                showProgressDialog();
            else
                disableBackButton();
            // TODO districts.  
            ForSaleServerManager.getInstance().getListings(this, mSearchQuery,
                    categoryId, -1, mSellingTypeId, mPageNumber, this);
    }
```

and in the following is setting data in the adapter

```
if (mPageNumber == 1) {

                                // add all pinning items.
                                if (items.getPinnedItems() != null && items.getPinnedItems().size() > 0)
                                    allItems.addAll(items.getPinnedItems());

                                if (mMode == MODE_SEARCH) {
                                    // handle post ad listing item.
                                    if ((allItems.size() % 2) != 0)
                                        allItems.add(new ItemResponse(ForSaleConstants.POST_AD_LISTING_ID));
                                }
                            }

                            // add all normal items.
                            if (items.getNormalItems() != null && items.getNormalItems().size() > 0)
                                for (int i = 0; i < items.getNormalItems().size(); i++) {
                                    if (allItems.contains(items.getNormalItems().get(i)) == false)
                                        allItems.add(items.getNormalItems().get(i));
                                }

                            if (allItems != null && allItems.size() > 0) {

                                if (mAdapter == null) {

                                    mAdapter = new ItemsListAdapter2(ItemsActivity.this, allItems);
                                    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                                    mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    mNoDataFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {

                                    mAdapter.setData(allItems);
                                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    mNoDataFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                            } else {

                                mListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mNoDataFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                showNoData(R.drawable.icon_listing_unselected, R.string.error_categories_found);
                            }
```

Comment: Please provide your ListAdapter and AsyncTask Code.

Comment: #1 consume/leak less memory #2 use a memory analyzer to find leaks/wasted memory

Comment: @JörnBuitink : Please reference to this question, I have used the solution of add two items in linear layout, I will edit the question with list adapter.

Comment: Please update mSearchQuery value into question.

Comment: Garima Mathur : I didn't understand what you want ?